# Can I host asp.net core 2.0 website on my godaddy shared hosting? Win and Linux both?

Tags: asp.net, shared-hosting

Microsoft is claiming that asp.net core is cross-platform. But most of the hostings today especially the shared one still don't support asp.net core website which is based on .net core.

I have Godaddy shared hosting one with windows and one with Linux. I am with no success to host my asp.net core website on both. Do I need to make some changes to run it on shared hosting?

Comment: You need to make sure that your hosting provider support ASP.NET Core. If you are unable to publish your .net core, what is the error message that you receive? Have you contact your hosting provider? I would recommend you to host it on Windows Server. I also use .net core here and publish it on Windows Server. I believe that Windows Server is more suitable to host .net Core application. FYI, I use asphostportal hosting plan here. They fully support .net core and it is working fine.

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/RunningASPNETCoreOnGoDaddysCheapestSharedLinuxHostingDontTryThisAtHome.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was asking GoDaddy support about this today (May 2019). Specifically I was asking about GoDaddy Plesk Shared Windows Hosting.

I asked what version of ASP.Net Core they supported. They directed me to the Plesk table on [this page](https://au.godaddy.com/help/software-versions-installed-on-hosting-accounts-897?v=1), which does not include .Net Core.

I asked when they would be adding support for .Net Core 2.2, and the support representative checked and said it was not on their road map.